# Positioning of canvas after the conversion from D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, position

I just managed to convert the respective heatmap from SVG to canvas. (due to large dataset vs performance issue) However the position of the generated heatmap has goes to a new region. I not sure how am I going to do about this. By changing the transform does not change anything as well.

My code:

```js
var units = [];
for(var unit_i = 0; unit_i<=101;){
 if(unit_i==0){
 units.push(1);
 unit_i = unit_i + 5;
 }
 else{
 units.push(unit_i);
 unit_i = unit_i + 4;
 }
}
var times = [];
for(var times_i = 0; times_i<=1440;){
 if(times_i==0){
 times.push(1);
 times_i = times_i + 10;
 }
 else{
 times.push(times_i);
 times_i = times_i + 9;
 }
}

var newSample = [{unit:null, timestamp: null, level: null}];


//by using below method we can observe the delay is not due to the data during insertion
for(var unit=1; unit<=99; unit++){
 for(var timestamp = 1; timestamp<=100; timestamp++){
  var i = Math.random() * 1400;
  newSample.push({unit:unit, timestamp: timestamp, level:i});
 }
}

var hours = 0;
var hoursIndicator = 0;
var margin = {
 top: 170,
 right: 100,
 bottom: 70,
 left: 100
};

var width = 2500,//optimized width
 //gridSize = Math.floor(width / times.length),//optimized gridsize
 gridSize = 10;//if 20 each interval will have 5
 height = 50 * (units.length); //optimized, the greater the length, the greater the height

console.log("this is gridSize:" + gridSize +", this is height: " + height + ", and this is width: " + width);

//SVG container
var svg = d3.select('.trafficCongestions')
 .append("svg")
 //.style("position", "absolute")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)//optimization
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)//optimization
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var canvas = d3.select('.trafficCongestions').append("canvas")
      .attr("id", "canvas")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)//optimization
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);//optimization

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

var detachedContainer = document.createElement("custom");
var dataContainer = d3.select(detachedContainer);

//Reset the overall font size
var newFontSize = width * 62.5 / 900;


//heatmap drawing starts from here
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(newSample, function(d, i) {return d.level; })/2, d3.max(newSample, function(d, i) {return d.level; })])
 .range(["#009933", "#FFCC00", "#990000"])//obtain the max data value of count


//y-axis (solely based on data of days)
var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
    .data(units)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { 
     return (i) * (gridSize * 4)/*adjusts the interval distance with (n - 1) concept*/; })
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize  + ")");

//x-axis (solely based on data of times)
var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
    .data(times)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
     var hrs = Math.floor(d/60);
    var mins = d%60;
     if(hrs<10){
       if(mins<10){
          return "0"+hrs + ":0" + mins;
       }
       return "0"+ hrs + ":" + mins;
     }
     return hrs +":"+ mins; 
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * (gridSize * 9)/*adjusts the interval distance with (n - 1) concept*/; })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1  + ", -6)")

 var heatMap = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect")
    .data(newSample)
    .enter().append("custom")
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
     return (d.timestamp - 1) * (gridSize); 
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
     console.log(d.unit);
     return (d.unit - 1) * (gridSize); 
    })
    .classed("rect", true)
    .attr("class", " rect bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .attr("strokeStyle", "rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)")//to have the middle line or not
    .attr("fillStyle", function(d,i){
     return colorScale(d.level);
    });

    drawCanvas();


//Append title to the top
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", -90)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Sample Result");
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "subtitle")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", -60)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("HEATMAP");

//Append credit at bottom
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "credit")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", gridSize * (units.length+1) + 80)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

//Extra scale since the color scale is interpolated
var countScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(newSample, function(d) {return d.level; })])
 .range([0, width])

//Calculate the variables for the temp gradient
var numStops = 10;
countRange = countScale.domain();
countRange[2] = countRange[1] - countRange[0];
countPoint = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numStops; i++) {
 countPoint.push(i * countRange[2]/(numStops-1) + countRange[0]);
}//for i

//Create the gradient
svg.append("defs")
 .append("linearGradient")
 .attr("id", "legendLevel")
 .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
 .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%")
 .selectAll("stop") 
 .data(d3.range(numStops))                
 .enter().append("stop") 
 .attr("offset", function(d,i) { 
  return countScale( countPoint[i] )/width;
 })   
 .attr("stop-color", function(d,i) { 
  return colorScale( countPoint[i] ); 
 });

var legendWidth = Math.min(width, 400);//the width of the legend
console.log(width);
//Color Legend container
var legendsvg = svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "legendWrapper")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (gridSize * 100 + 40) + ")");

//Draw the Rectangle
legendsvg.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "legendRect")
 .attr("x", -legendWidth/2)
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("width", legendWidth)
 .attr("height", 10)
 .style("fill", "url(#legendLevel)");
 
//Append title
legendsvg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "legendTitle")
 .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", -10)
 .style("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text("Level");

//Set scale for x-axis
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([-legendWidth/2, legendWidth/2])
  .domain([ 0, d3.max(newSample, function(d) { return d.level; })] );

//Define x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
   .ticks(5)
   .scale(xScale);

//Set up X axis
legendsvg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (10) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

function drawCanvas(){

 var elements = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect");

 elements.each(function(d){
  var node = d3.select(this);

  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
  context.rect(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("width"), node.attr("height"));
     context.fill();
     context.closePath();
 });
}
```

```css
html { font-size: 100%; } 


    .timeLabel, .dayLabel {
        font-size: 1rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        fill: #4F4F4F;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .subtitle {
        font-size: 1.0rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
      
    .credit {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .axis path, .axis tick, .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: none;
      }  

    .legendTitle {
          font-size: 1.3rem;
          fill: #4F4F4F;
          font-weight: 300;
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="trafficCongestions" class="trafficCongestions"></div>
```

Comment: *"I just managed to convert the respective heatmap from d3js to canvas"*... this makes no sense to me. I believe you meant *"from SVG to canvas"*, is that right? Also, your snippet is freezing the browser.

Comment: Hi Gerardo i have made those changes. in fact the reason behind the freezing is due to the sample data size. Now should be okay, kindly refer and help me. :)

Comment: Yes, not freezing now.

Comment: I see that you're using `svg` for just the texts and the legends. So why don't you position the canvas **absolute** as a layer over the svg? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using `svg` to just show up the `text` and `legend`, I'd say you can absolute position the canvas on top of the SVG - by CSS.

Here are the CSS changes:

```
div#trafficCongestions {
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

You can do the above using `d3 style` as well `cause the **margins** are defined in the script. I just wanted to show that this is an option to use.

```js
var units = [];
for(var unit_i = 0; unit_i<=101;){
 if(unit_i==0){
 units.push(1);
 unit_i = unit_i + 5;
 }
 else{
 units.push(unit_i);
 unit_i = unit_i + 4;
 }
}
var times = [];
for(var times_i = 0; times_i<=1440;){
 if(times_i==0){
 times.push(1);
 times_i = times_i + 10;
 }
 else{
 times.push(times_i);
 times_i = times_i + 9;
 }
}

var newSample = [{unit:null, timestamp: null, level: null}];


//by using below method we can observe the delay is not due to the data during insertion
for(var unit=1; unit<=99; unit++){
 for(var timestamp = 1; timestamp<=100; timestamp++){
  var i = Math.random() * 1400;
  newSample.push({unit:unit, timestamp: timestamp, level:i});
 }
}

var hours = 0;
var hoursIndicator = 0;
var margin = {
 top: 170,
 right: 100,
 bottom: 70,
 left: 100
};

var width = 2500,//optimized width
 //gridSize = Math.floor(width / times.length),//optimized gridsize
 gridSize = 10;//if 20 each interval will have 5
 height = 50 * (units.length); //optimized, the greater the length, the greater the height

//console.log("this is gridSize:" + gridSize +", this is height: " + height + ", and this is width: " + width);

//SVG container
var svg = d3.select('.trafficCongestions')
 .append("svg")
 //.style("position", "absolute")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)//optimization
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)//optimization
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var canvas = d3.select('.trafficCongestions').append("canvas")
      .attr("id", "canvas")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)//optimization
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);//optimization

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

var detachedContainer = document.createElement("custom");
var dataContainer = d3.select(detachedContainer);

//Reset the overall font size
var newFontSize = width * 62.5 / 900;


//heatmap drawing starts from here
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(newSample, function(d, i) {return d.level; })/2, d3.max(newSample, function(d, i) {return d.level; })])
 .range(["#009933", "#FFCC00", "#990000"])//obtain the max data value of count


//y-axis (solely based on data of days)
var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
    .data(units)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { 
     return (i) * (gridSize * 4)/*adjusts the interval distance with (n - 1) concept*/; })
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize  + ")");

//x-axis (solely based on data of times)
var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
    .data(times)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
     var hrs = Math.floor(d/60);
    var mins = d%60;
     if(hrs<10){
       if(mins<10){
          return "0"+hrs + ":0" + mins;
       }
       return "0"+ hrs + ":" + mins;
     }
     return hrs +":"+ mins; 
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * (gridSize * 9)/*adjusts the interval distance with (n - 1) concept*/; })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1  + ", -6)")

 var heatMap = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect")
    .data(newSample)
    .enter().append("custom")
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
     return (d.timestamp - 1) * (gridSize); 
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
     //console.log(d.unit);
     return (d.unit - 1) * (gridSize); 
    })
    .classed("rect", true)
    .attr("class", " rect bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .attr("strokeStyle", "rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)")//to have the middle line or not
    .attr("fillStyle", function(d,i){
     return colorScale(d.level);
    });

    drawCanvas();


//Append title to the top
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", -90)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Sample Result");
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "subtitle")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", -60)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("HEATMAP");

//Append credit at bottom
svg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "credit")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", gridSize * (units.length+1) + 80)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

//Extra scale since the color scale is interpolated
var countScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(newSample, function(d) {return d.level; })])
 .range([0, width])

//Calculate the variables for the temp gradient
var numStops = 10;
countRange = countScale.domain();
countRange[2] = countRange[1] - countRange[0];
countPoint = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numStops; i++) {
 countPoint.push(i * countRange[2]/(numStops-1) + countRange[0]);
}//for i

//Create the gradient
svg.append("defs")
 .append("linearGradient")
 .attr("id", "legendLevel")
 .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
 .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%")
 .selectAll("stop") 
 .data(d3.range(numStops))                
 .enter().append("stop") 
 .attr("offset", function(d,i) { 
  return countScale( countPoint[i] )/width;
 })   
 .attr("stop-color", function(d,i) { 
  return colorScale( countPoint[i] ); 
 });

var legendWidth = Math.min(width, 400);//the width of the legend
//console.log(width);
//Color Legend container
var legendsvg = svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "legendWrapper")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (gridSize * 100 + 40) + ")");

//Draw the Rectangle
legendsvg.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "legendRect")
 .attr("x", -legendWidth/2)
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("width", legendWidth)
 .attr("height", 10)
 .style("fill", "url(#legendLevel)");
 
//Append title
legendsvg.append("text")
 .attr("class", "legendTitle")
 .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", -10)
 .style("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text("Level");

//Set scale for x-axis
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([-legendWidth/2, legendWidth/2])
  .domain([ 0, d3.max(newSample, function(d) { return d.level; })] );

//Define x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
   .ticks(5)
   .scale(xScale);

//Set up X axis
legendsvg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (10) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

function drawCanvas(){

 var elements = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.rect");

 elements.each(function(d){
  var node = d3.select(this);

  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
  context.rect(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("width"), node.attr("height"));
     context.fill();
     context.closePath();
 });
}
```

```css
html { font-size: 100%; } 

div#trafficCongestions {
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 100px;
}
    .timeLabel, .dayLabel {
        font-size: 1rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        fill: #4F4F4F;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .subtitle {
        font-size: 1.0rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
      
    .credit {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        fill: #AAAAAA;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .axis path, .axis tick, .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: none;
      }  

    .legendTitle {
          font-size: 1.3rem;
          fill: #4F4F4F;
          font-weight: 300;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="trafficCongestions" class="trafficCongestions"></div>
```

Let me know if this makes sense. If not, let's look for other approaches.

**Edit as per comments: (visual studio didn't support the CSS styling added by above approach)**

Added the style using `d3`:

```
canvas.style('position', 'absolute').style('top', margin.top+'px').style('left', margin.left+'px')
```

And this worked.

Comment: Hi Shashank, thanks for your suggestion. This does solve my problem. In fact, I have implemented above method by using d3 style. Method works well in normal html file. However it doesn't work in my visual studio project. Notice that the syntax are all the same, however only the absolute style is shown but not the top and left (when viewed in browser console). Sometimes, I just don't know why visual studio always has such issue. By the way, using css does work.

Comment: Can you try adding this style i.e. `position: absolute, top: margin.top and left: margin.left` using d3? For example (in your case): `canvas.style('position', 'absolute').style('top', margin.top+'px').style('left', margin.left+'px')` ?

Comment: hey man, thank you so much. Tested and it is working. Well really weird, it did work with normal html file when I am using just `canvas.style('position', 'absolute').style('top', '170').style('left', '100')`. Anyhow I have gotten what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Added the new solution (fix) to the answer.

Comment: Marked the given solution as answer. :)